# Prolog: How to write a predicate that calculates an integral?

Tags: parameters, prolog, predicate, integral

I want to write a prediacte integrate(A, B, N, F, R), A is the lower boundary, B is the upper boundary, N is the number of intervalls, F is the function, R is the Result.
This is the pseudo code that I want to use to model my prediacte:

```
R = 0;
D = (B − A)/N;
R = F(A) + F(B);
I = 1;
while I =< N do
K = A + I ∗ D;
if I % 2 == 0; then
R = R + 2 ∗ F(K);
else
R = R + 4 ∗ F(K);
end if
I = I + 1;
end while
R = R + D/3;
return R;
```

The function for the integral is: `f(X, Y) :- Y is 1/(1+(X^2)).`

So far this is what I have:

```
int(A, B, 0, I, D, F, R).
int(A, B, N, I, D, F, R) :- (I mod 2) == 0, K is ((I*D) + A),
                            call(F, K, X), R is R + 2*X, 
                            I is I +1,
                            int(A, B, N, I, D, F, R).
int(A, B, s(N), 1, F, R) :- (I mod 2) == 1, K is ((I*D) + A),
                            call(F, K, X), R is R + 4*X, 
                            I is I +1,
                            int(A, B, N, I, D, F, R).
integrate(A, B, N, F, R) :- R1 is 0, D is ((B-A)/N),
                            call(F, A, X), call(F, B, Y), R1 is X + Y,
                            int(A, B, N, 1, D, F, R1), R is R1 + D/3.
```

This gives me an error: arguments are  not sufficiently instantiated. I don't want to modify the parameters of integrate(). What would be the correct way to use call in this case? A solution would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you figure out what gives you the error? Maybe you can narrow it down a bit and show how you run it? As it stands, this: `(I mod 2) == 1` is always going to fail. You probably meant to write `I mod 2 =:= 1`, which does something else. You can probably look it up yourself in the docs of the Prolog implementation you are using. Shortly, `==/2` is "equivalence" and `=:=/2` is arithmetic comparison.

Comment: Hmm, another thing: `D is ((B-A)/N)` is also going to throw an error. You should really narrow down your problem on your own first, and show how you run this code.